# How to horizontal align titles, author names and affiliations in APA6 in latex

Tags: latex

I am currently using the following latex code.

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{Example of journal article}

\twoauthors{Author One}{Author Two}
\twoaffiliations{Institute of Psychology}{Freud's Institute}

\abstract{This is an example of a journal article using the \texttt{apa6.cls} document class to typeset manuscripts according to 6th edition of the Americal Psychological Association (APA) manual}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Sample section}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

The title, author names and affiliations are currently centered. I want to left align them as shown in figure below.

[image]

I tried the solutions provided for `article document type` in other questions. But they did not work for my template.

Please let me know if any details are needed.

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [How to left align titles and author details in apa6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469636/5764)

Comment: Link above leads to a 404 in the other community. I guess we will never know the answer.